# how to BlocBuilder in stepper

Tags: flutter, bloc, sqflite

How can I implement bloc in stepper?

> code section  if (isLastStep) 
> will bring BlocBuilder will bring BlocBuilder to use?

i am learning bloc (super newbie)
Is there a simple example way to use Bloc with a stepper?

In the data entry page, use the Stepper to collect data by giving

Step 1 Collect Personal Information

Step 2 Collect address information according to ID card.

````
import 'package:example1/bloc/stepbloc.dart';
import 'package:example1/bloc/stepevent.dart';
import 'package:example1/bloc/stepstate.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

class Adddata extends StatefulWidget {
  const Adddata({super.key});

  @override
  State<Adddata> createState() => _AdddataState();
}

class _AdddataState extends State<Adddata> {
  final TextEditingController fullnameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController telController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController addressController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController postcodeController = TextEditingController();

  int currentStep = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("กรอกข้อมูล"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Stepper(
        type: StepperType.horizontal,
        steps: getSteps(),
        currentStep: currentStep,
        onStepContinue: () {
          final isLastStep = currentStep == getSteps().length - 1;
          if (isLastStep) {
            BlocBuilder<StepBloc, STEPState>(builder: (context, state) {
              return InkWell(onTap: () async {
                context.read<StepBloc>().add(AddStepEvent(
                    const Uuid().v4(),
                    fullnameController.text,
                    emailController.text,
                    telController.text,
                    addressController.text,
                    postcodeController.text));
                context.read<StepBloc>().add(FetchStepEvent());
                if (!mounted) return;
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              });
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              currentStep += 1;
            });
          }
        },
        onStepCancel: () {
          currentStep == 0
              ? null
              : setState(() {
                  currentStep -= 1;
                });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Step> getSteps() => [
        Step(
          state: currentStep > 0 ? StepState.complete : StepState.indexed,
          isActive: currentStep >= 0,
          title: Text('Personal'),
          content: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: fullnameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "ชื่อ-นามสกุล"),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: emailController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "e-mail"),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: telController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "เบอร์โทร"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Step(
          state: currentStep > 1 ? StepState.complete : StepState.indexed,
          isActive: currentStep >= 1,
          title: Text('Address ID'),
          content: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                minLines: 1,
                maxLines: 5,
                controller: addressController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "ที่อยู่"),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: postcodeController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "รหัสไปรษณีย์"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Step(
          isActive: currentStep == 2,
          title: Text('Complete'),
          content: Column(
            children: [
              Text('ชื่อ-นามสกุล : ${fullnameController.text}'),
              Text('e-mail : ${emailController.text}'),
              Text('เบอร์โทร : ${telController.text}'),
              Text('ที่อยู่ : ${addressController.text}'),
              Text('รหัสไปรษณีย์ : ${postcodeController.text}'),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ];
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

`BlocBuilder` is a widget you can't just use it in the function.

For your issue you need to wrap the `Stepper` widget inside the `BlocListener` and  in the listener add your states, like bloc emits Success state do something, in error state do something and more.

And in the `onStepContinue` you will check if it's last step then add the event.

refer the below code:

```
BlocListener<StepBloc, STEPState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if(state is SuccessState){
          // do something
        }else{
          // add more condition if there's more states.
        }
      },
      child: Stepper(
        steps: [],
        onStepContinue: () {
          final isLastStep = currentStep == getSteps().length - 1;
          if (isLastStep) {
            context.read<StepBloc>().add(AddStepEvent(
                const Uuid().v4(),
                fullnameController.text,
                emailController.text,
                telController.text,
                addressController.text,
                postcodeController.text));
            context.read<StepBloc>().add(FetchStepEvent());
          }
        },
      ),
    )
```

Comment: I tried getting the InititalStepState to succeed and printing the value of test , but it shows neither true no false.

Comment: you're have wrapped the `MaterialApp` with `BlocProvider` right?? if not you need to take a instance of the bloc and pass it to the `BlocListener`. And the event will be added through that instance only.